# Сомневаюсь по поводу тире

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли не ставить тире между "фотоотчёте" и "24" в таком предложении:

"**В полном фотоотчёте 24 фото**"?

Comment: Если заменить «24 фото» на «24 снимка», то будет правильно по двум соображениям: одно чисто по тексту с повтором, второе по, что очень возможно, цифровой версии фотоотчёта.

Answer (score 2):

**Тире в Вашем предложении можно ставить, а можно и не ставить.** Всё зависит от того, как произносится фраза. Вот цитата из справочника:

"**Тире ставится** в так называемых эллиптических предложениях при желании автора подчеркнуть обстоятельство места (что, как правило, сопровождается наличием паузы), например:

***Вокруг месяца – бледные круги (А.Н. Толстой); Над площадью – низко повисшая пыль, на площади – порожние бутылки казенки, бумажки дешевых конфет (Шолохов); И по всему небу – облака, как розовые перышки... (В. Панова); На бескозырках – пехотные каски (Е. Долматовский).***

**При отсутствии паузы тире может не ставиться**, например:

***Там на неведомых дорожках следы невиданных зверей... (Пушкин); Скрип шагов вдоль улиц белых, огоньки вдали (Фет); В углу старый кожаный диван. В другом углу, позади письменного стола, несгораемый шкаф. На полу ковер (Симонов)*** (так обычно оформляются ремарки в пьесах)". [Розенталь. Справочник](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm)

Answer (score 1):

В полном фотоотчёте 24 фото.

Лучше тире **не ставить**, если это просто информация о количестве фото.

Если тире будет поставлено, то при наличии паузы **логически подчеркивается** сочетание "в полном фотоотчете", он как бы противопоставляется  фотоотчету "неполному".

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня уже есть тире в предложении, и я не хотел бы ставить второе. В действительности я привёл только небольшую часть предложения. Полное предложение такое:

Comment: Здесь показаны 8 уменьшенных фотографий – в полном фотоотчёте 24 фото размером 2000 x 2000 пикселей (в формате JPEG).

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта нормативны и в общем-то равноправны.
Тире лучше поставить только если хочется большей наглядности. Других **приоритетных** мотивов я тут не вижу. 
Остальное - см. Екатерина Каштанова.